# Function doesn't run at all if specific line is not commented out

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, mqtt

I'm debugging an application that is hard to test. In short, the application runs on a Raspberry Pi (Node v10.23.0) and listens for MQTT messages.

Below, you will see a function `handleMessage`. The class where this function is defined inherits from EventEmitter (which is where `emit` is defined). The function is bound to the correct instance.

The function checks the topic of the incoming message. Depending on the topic, it will do different things. To simplify, I have included two topics in the below example. The "cmd" topic is a command.

This works just fine so far. If I send a "cmd" message, with a "cmd/[client id]" topic and some payload, I can see in the logs:

```
... (previous logs)
in handleMessage. Topic = cmd/[client id], Payload = {"name": "get-local-time"}
COMMAND!
Command name is: get-local-time
GENERIC COMMAND!
```

However, when a command is received, we want to emit a "command" event to be handled by some other module. **As soon as I add this line...**

`this.emit("command", command)`

... then, the logs stop here:

```
... (previous logs)
```

The function:

```
handleMessage(topic, payload) {
  console.log(`in handleMessage. Topic = ${topic}, Payload = ${payload}`)

  switch(topic) {
    case `someTopic/${this.clientId}`: {
      console.log("NOT A COMMAND!")
      break
    }
    case `cmd/${this.clientId}`: {
      console.log("COMMAND!")

      let command = JSON.parse(payload.toString())

      console.log("Command name is: " + command.name)

      if (command.name === "some-special-command") {
        console.log("some-special-command")
      } else {
        console.log("GENERIC COMMAND!")
        // UNCOMMENTING THIS LINE CAUSES THE WHOLE FUNCTION TO NOT BE CALLED:
        // this.emit("command", command)
      }
      break
    }
    default: {
      console.log("NOT SUPPORTED")
      break
    }
  }
}
```

The code runs synchronously. If I replace `this.emit("command", command)` with `throw new Error("find me")`, I see the error in the logs, so it's not an issue with `this.emit` throwing. Even if it did throw, I should still see the output produced before the exception, right?

What could possibly cause a function not to run at all, just because of a single line (that doesn't break syntax)?

**Update: Extra info**

I added another log statement:

```
...
console.log("WHAT IS THIS.EMIT? " + this.emit)
// Uncommenting this line causes the whole function not to run at all:
// this.emit("command", command)
```

And the output of that is:

```
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]: WHAT IS THIS.EMIT? function emit(type, ...args) {
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:   let doError = (type === 'error');
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:   const events = this._events;
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:   if (events !== undefined)
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     doError = (doError && events.error === undefined);
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:   else if (!doError)
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     return false;
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:   // If there is no 'error' event listener then throw.
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:   if (doError) {
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     let er;
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     if (args.length > 0)
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:       er = args[0];
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     if (er instanceof Error) {
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:       try {
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:         const { kExpandStackSymbol } = require('internal/util');
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:         const capture = {};
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:         Error.captureStackTrace(capture, EventEmitter.prototype.emit);
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:         Object.defineProperty(er, kExpandStackSymbol, {
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:           value: enhanceStackTrace.bind(null, er, capture),
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:           configurable: true
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:         });
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:       } catch {}
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:       // Note: The comments on the `throw` lines are intentional, they show
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:       // up in Node's output if this results in an unhandled exception.
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     }
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     let stringifiedEr;
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     const { inspect } = require('internal/util/inspect');
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     try {
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:       stringifiedEr = inspect(er);
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     } catch {
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:       stringifiedEr = er;
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     }
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     // At least give some kind of context to the user
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     const errors = lazyErrors();
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     const err = new errors.ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR(stringifiedEr);
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     err.context = er;
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     throw err; // Unhandled 'error' event
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:   }
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:   const handler = events[type];
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:   if (handler === undefined)
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     return false;
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:   if (typeof handler === 'function') {
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     Reflect.apply(handler, this, args);
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:   } else {
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     const len = handler.length;
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     const listeners = arrayClone(handler, len);
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:     for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i)
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:       Reflect.apply(listeners[i], this, args);
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:   }
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]:   return true;
Nov 30 20:36:33 raspberrypi node[2667]: }
```

The project uses webpack. The statement is included in the build output.

**Update 2: Context**
More information is clearly needed. I can't copy and paste the entire class (due to a strict NDA), but here's the gist of it:

```
import awsIot from 'aws-iot-device-sdk';
import EventEmitter from 'events';

// Note that EventEmitter is not actually defined as a class, but a 
// "function class". Not sure if that matters, but this.emit
// (defined in EventEmitter) is available and has the expected
// definition.

class IotClient extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(clientId, host, credentials) {
    super()
    this.clientId = clientId
    this.host = host
    this.credentials = credentials

    // Actually happens in a different "initialize" method, which is
    // actually called and works as expected.
    const options = {
      host: this.host,
      clientId: this.clientId,
      ...this.credentials,
    }
    this.device = awsIot.device(options)
    this.device.subscribe(`cmd/${this.clientId}`)
    
    this.handleMessage = this.handleMessage.bind(this)
    this.device.on("message", this.handleMessage)
  }

  handleMessage(topic, payload) {
    // SEE ORIGINAL POST FOR FUNCTION CONTENTS
  }  
}

// app.js, called on service start
const iotClient = new IotClient(
  clientId,
  iotClientOptions.host,
  credentials,
)

// Yes, this is redundant. Should not matter.
const emitter = new EventEmitter()

// NOTE: Not "cmd", but "command"
iotClient.on('command', (command) => emitter.emit('dispatch-command', command))
```

Also, note that `this` in the context of `handleMessage` is for sure the instance of the `IotClient` class. I (think I) know this because:

1. `if (!this instanceof IotClient) { throw new Error() }` does not throw (I guess at this point, all expectations are out of the window, so proceed to 2.)
2. `this.clientId` is available, and `awsIot.device` does not have `clientId`
3. If I set `this.findme = "FINDME"` in the constructor of `IotClient` and log `this.findme` in `handleMessage`, I get `FINDME`. If that's not damning evidence that `this` is an instance of IotClient, I'm not sure what is.

Comment: Maybe its contaminated. Try deleting it along with some of the lines it touches. Then write them again manually.

Comment: @skara9 No success. :(

Comment: Are you sure this is related to `emit`? `command` declaration seems a bit strange. Is `payload` a string or an object? If it's an object `.toString()` will convert it to `[object Object]` and JSON.parse will break. Also, you're missing `=` before `JSON.parse` on `command`? If `command` is not a problem can you share the class where the function is defined?

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70175685/edit) the question to show how you are using the  `handleMessage` function. But `this` will not be what you think it is, it will be the scope of the MQTT client not your class. (add a `console.log(this)` in `handleMessage`)

Comment: @hardillb Thank you. I will edit my question to show the context in which handleMessage is defined and called. But `this` is what I think it is, because I have already logged `this`, verified that `this.clientId` is available, that `this.emit` is available, etc. As explained, `handleMessage` is bound to the instance of the class that defines it, i.e.: `this.handleMessage = this.handleMessage.bind(this)`. I also tried: `if (!(this instanceof MyClass)) { throw new Error() }`

Comment: @hardillb Edited the question to include proof that `this` is the expected instance of `IotClient`.

Comment: This seems like a case for debugging.  Set a breakpoint and step through the `this.emit()` in the debugger and watch what happens.  That's why we have these types of debugging tools.  It seems like either `this` has been corrupted, `this.emit()` has been corrupted or one of the listeners for that event is causing a problem or the problem isn't on the exact line of code you think it is.  All of these can be confirmed or ruled out by stepping through the code in the debugger.  Most likely an exception is getting thrown and it's getting eaten (not shown).

Comment: @jfriend00 The problem is that this project was never set up for unit tests. I have set up some (with great effort), but actually running the whole application requires a very specific environment that I'm not easily able to replicate. In other words, I'm not able to step through this execution without significant effort to refactor out all the problematic dependencies (hard-coded unix paths, for example). I will try some hacks first. The only things I can think of that would be able to cause this sort of behavior are bugs in Node and reflection.

Comment: If it's difficult to run the debugger in the actual run-time environment (I'm still not sure why), then just put `console.log()` statements all over the relevant code and trace its progress that way.  You may even want to put them in whoever is listening for the emitted event too.  Ultimately this is a troubleshooting problem and you need more info on what's happening because code inspection can only go so far.  The odds of you running into an actual node bug here with something as simple as `.emit()` is pretty low.  But, either way, you still need more data on the situation to narrow it down.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's pretty much what I've been doing. There's a log statement at nearly every statement (except in third-party packages). I'm not sure how I would describe "uncommenting a line causes all statements before it to not run" if not a bug in either node or webpack. I can't think of any situation in any environment where adding a statement __later__ in a function prevents __previous__ statements from executing when the function is called, or where adding a line to a function would have any effect on whether or not that function is called when the conditions are true. I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `super()` in your constructor and you need to do so BEFORE you reference `this` in your constructor.  This is required to properly initialize your base class instance state.

```
class IotClient extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(clientId, host, credentials) {
    super();                                    // <=== Add this

    this.clientId = clientId
    this.host = host
    this.credentials = credentials

    // Actually happens in a different "initialize" method, which is
    // actually called and works as expected.
    const options = {
      host: this.host,
      clientId: this.clientId,
      ...this.credentials,
    }
    this.device = awsIot.device(options)
    this.device.subscribe(`cmd/${this.clientId}`)
    
    this.handleMessage = this.handleMessage.bind(this)
    this.device.on("message", this.handleMessage)
  }

  handleMessage(topic, payload) {
    // SEE ORIGINAL POST FOR FUNCTION CONTENTS
  }  
}
```

---

What baffles me is that this should be a run-time error:

```
this.clientId = clientId
        ^

ReferenceError: Must call super constructor in derived class before 
accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor
```

Because that's exactly what I get when I try to run your code.

Comment: That's just another one of my bad simplifications. The call to super is included. Sorry about that. Updating my answer with the real solution.

Comment: @404usernamenotfound - OK, I don't think I can help further.  The issue is probably caused by something in the code you aren't showing us.  If you can reproduce the issue in code you can show us, I'll dive in again.  But without seeing all of the real code or without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I don't think there's much else I can do.

Comment: I figured it out (the way I was viewing the logs was the issue, not the code itself). I really appreciate and thank you for your great ideas.

Answer (score 0):

**First answer**

I managed to work around this weird issue by **not** inheriting from EventEmitter (note that `utils.inherits` had the same effect), and instead doing:

```
const emitter = new EventEmitter()

class IotClient {
    emit(...args) {
        return emitter.emit(...args)
    }
    on(...args) {
        emitter.on(...args)
    }
}
```

So it seems that inheriting from EventEmitter was at least part of the reason this wasn't working (even though inheriting from EventEmitter is supposed to be supported).

**Actual solution**

The real problem was the logs. An exception was thrown due to a different method (that would eventually be called as a result of `this.emit(...)`) not being bound.

The logs *were* being written, and the statements *were* being hit, but because of an exception up the call stack, logs from lower in the call stack were not included in the output from `systemctl status`. They were, however, included in the output form `journalctl`, which showed not only the missing logs, but also the exception that caused all my problems. `systemctl status` must have different rules for what output is displayed than `journalctl` does.

Not sure why I could see my `throw new Error("find me")` exception using `systemctl status` and not the one occurring in an event listener, but that seems to have been the case.

Lesson learned: Use `journalctl` for debugging, not `systemctl status`.

Comment: See my answer.  You weren't doing the inheritance properly in the code you show in your question.  You must call `super()` in the constructor when using the `class` syntax as that's how the base class constructor gets called.  Not initializing the base class properly can lead to all sorts of weird errors.  FYI, zillions of things inherit from `EventEmitter`.  It is probably the most inherited from class so inheritance from it definitely works when implemented properly.